# Assign transformer layers to BERT weights

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, large-language-model

I print the weight names and shape of the BERT transformer. Now, I want to assign the printed weights to the layers in the transformers architecture:
[image]

In the following, I can assign query, key and value weights to the linear layers in the attention block:

[image]

But, in the print there are `attention.output.dense.weight` and `attention.output.LayerNorm.weight`, where can I find it in the architecture of transformer/attention-head?

Further there is an intermediate.dense.weight and there `output.dense.weight` and `output.LayerNorm.weight`. Are they parts of *Add & Norm* after the multi-head-attention blocks?

Answer (score 0):

In the BERT architecture, various components work together to process the input data, including attention blocks, linear layers, and normalization layers. Here's a breakdown of the weights you mentioned:

- `attention.output.dense.weight`: After the scaled dot-product attention in each head, the results are concatenated and then linearly transformed using this weight. This is essentially the output linear layer of the multi-head attention block.
- `attention.output.LayerNorm.weight` is the weight for the layer normalization that is typically applied after the attention block and the residual connection (Add & Norm). It normalizes the output of the attention block before it is passed to the next layer.
- `intermediate.dense.weight` belongs to the first linear layer of the feed-forward network (FFN) that follows the multi-head attention block in each transformer layer. This layer typically uses a ReLU (or similar) activation function and expands the dimensionality of the input.
- `output.dense.weight` is the weight of the second linear layer in the FFN, which usually reduces the dimensionality back to the original size.
- `output.LayerNorm.weight`: Similar to the `attention.output.LayerNorm.weight`, this is the weight for the layer normalization applied after the feed-forward network and the residual connection.